# on Solidus 1.3 fresh install: Validation failed: Store can't be blank when adding to cart (on solidus hello-world install, v1.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

I get this when I click "Add to Cart" on a basic product. In my spree_stores table I have a single record for 'Sample Store' as it was populated by the generators (?)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in Spree::OrdersController#populate
Validation failed: Store can't be blank

full stacktrace:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46b17070a302079102640f70fca219ae

Gemfile.lock
https://gist.github.com/jasonfb/024fc7c9435d30ea362979dad1f42884

Answer (score 2):

this was fixed by manually setting the 'default' flag on the 'Sample Store' record in spree_stores to true (1)

[image: before]

changed to

[image: after]